# Definition of cochain algebra

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

In Felix, Halperin, Thomas "Rational homotopy theory" on page 46 we find the following definition :

> > A cochain algebra is a dga 
> >     $(R, d)$ with $R = \{R^n\}_{n\ge o}$.

I can't get the definition of a cochain algebra, I mean what is special about a cochain algebra that leads to have the distinguished name of cochain algebra among other dga's ( Differential Graded Algebra) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it comes from historical reasons, cochain algebras were invented first.
Furthemore, there is a difference between bounded and unbounded dga, for example in term of convergence of spectral sequences.